# Blend switch between 2 visual states (WP7.1)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend, behavior

I think what I am doing is fairly simple, I guess I am just missing something.

I have a StackPanel inside another StackPanel. What I want to do is to hide / show the inner one when the outter one is clicked.

I have 2 states in blend. First makes a StackPanel Collapsed, the other one Expanded.

I added 2 behaviours (GoToStateBaheviour) to the outter StackPanel and assigned their triggers to MouseLeftButtonDown event. In the first behaviour in Conditions I check whether the the inner StackPanel is collapsed, if it is it switches to the state Expanded. 
The other behaviour works vice versa - in Conditions I check whether the the inner StackPanel is visible, if it is it switches to the state Collapsed.

Now both of these Behaviours individualy work just fine. But combined, not a chance. I tried to change the Event name of one of them to "ManipulationDelta" and then both started working - but to activate the one I have to try to drag it.

Seems like having 2 behaviours attached to the same event is causing a trouble. What would you recommend?

EDIT

I uploaded the entire solution so you can open it in Blend
http://leteckaposta.cz/800017526

(The project is for WPF as opposed to the one I have for WP7, but that shouldnt matter)
I changed the behaviour to ChangePropertyAction, which should make it easier to read. There are two of them - both react to MouseLeftButtonDown with a Condition for Visibility property. one of them changes it to Visible, the other one to Collapsed. 
But only one of them works. I suspect it is always the "upper one" (the one that comes first). Feel free to test it out yourselves

CODE

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <StackPanel Height="168" Width="305" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF7C7070">
            <TextBlock Height="59" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Outter">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                                <ei:ConditionalExpression>
                                    <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=stackPanel}" Operator="Equal">
                                        <ei:ComparisonCondition.RightOperand>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </ei:ComparisonCondition.RightOperand>
                                    </ei:ComparisonCondition>
                                </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                            </ei:ConditionBehavior>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=stackPanel}" PropertyName="Visibility">
                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                            </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                                <ei:ConditionalExpression>
                                    <ei:ComparisonCondition LeftOperand="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=stackPanel}" Operator="NotEqual">
                                        <ei:ComparisonCondition.RightOperand>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </ei:ComparisonCondition.RightOperand>
                                    </ei:ComparisonCondition>
                                </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                            </ei:ConditionBehavior>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=stackPanel}" PropertyName="Visibility">
                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
            <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Height="106" RenderTransformOrigin="0.489,-0.842" Background="#FF708B7C" Visibility="Hidden">
                <TextBlock Height="50" Margin="74,0,65,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Inner"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Maybe inner `StackPanel` is suppressed `MouseLeftButtonDown` on outer `StackPanel` when inner is `Visible`...

Comment: Thats not the case - as I wrote, when there is only one behaviour (say the one that check if the inner is visible and then hides it) it works fine

Comment: Show your code, don't just describe it or we have to guess at what may be wrong. Help us to help you.

Comment: I think you may have the same problem as I do. It looks like these triggers fire sequentially, not simultaneously, so the first one fires, updates the Visibility to Collapsed and then the second one fires with the binding referring to the revised Visibility (Collapsed) and so it immediately is made visible again - this can be tested by switching the events in the XAML, one way around will cause it to be held in the Collapsed state, the other way around will cause it to be held in the Visible state.

Answer (score 0):

As you've commented in [Chris W.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9710203/9664), when you place both triggers in the same event, they compete against each other and cancel each other out. You can verify this by using a `MouseLeftButtonUp` on one of the triggers.

A simple code behind event can resolve this issue.

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel Background="Red" MouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseLeftButtonDown">
        <TextBlock FontSize="22" Text="Outter" />
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel"
                    Height="75"
                    Background="Yellow">
            <TextBlock FontSize="22" Text="Inner" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
{
    stackPanel.Visibility = stackPanel.Visibility == Visibility.Visible
                                    ? Visibility.Collapsed
                                    : Visibility.Visible;

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your triggers are firing sequentially and not simultaneously. Here is what is happening,

1. MouseLeftButtonDown event fired
2. First trigger activates, checks the `Visibility`, it is Visible so it changes it to Collapsed
3. Second trigger activates, checks the `Visibility` it is Collapsed so it changes it to Visible

The net result is that it is stuck in the Visible state. You can verify this by changing the order of the Triggers - the result will be stuck in the Collapsed state.

One way around this that does not require code-behind for each instance is to use a `Converter` which 'flips' Visible to Collapsed. you can then use a `ChangePropertyAction` to set a value which is determined via a Binding through this converter, e.g.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
        <ec:ChangePropertyAction 
            TargetName="stackPanel"
            PropertyName="Visibility"
            Value="{Binding Visibility, 
                Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToOpposite}, 
                ElementName=stackPanel}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The Converter looks like this,

```
public class VisibilityToOpposite : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        Visibility vis = (Visibility)value;
        return (vis == Visibility.Collapsed) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The great thing about this method is that the Converter can be reused and also is not limited to two states e.g.

```
public class StringToNextString : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string s = (string)value;
        List<string> allStrings = (parameter as string).Split(new char[] { '|' }).ToList();
        // Find the index of the next string along
        int i = allStrings.IndexOf(s);
        i = (i + 1) % allStrings.Count;
        return allStrings[i];
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then call with a ConverterParameter of pipe delimited strings to cycle through e.g.

```
Value="{Binding Text, ConverterParameter=one|two|three, 
    Converter={StaticResource StringToNextString}, 
    ElementName=stackPanel}"
```